# Selecting Combobox key in System.out.println

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jcomponent

[image: The key / value pair I'm trying to select]

I'm trying to select the keys and values in color but I can't seem to do it through the getComponent(1) even though it list them. The components as comboboxes.[image] 
GamePanel is just an ArrayList of JPanels and I would hope people knows what the get does. So far when a button is pressed it system.out.println the following statements but I can't seem to access the keys. I tried the Arrays.toString method, that doesn't work. I also tried manually creating an array with the split method and that doesn't work. I can't convert the key/value pairs to an array because it's a component.

Comment: The short answer is, don't do this. It will break your code way to easily. Instead, provide simply getters to return the values of the components, which should be maintained through the use of instance fields